# Hiding elements using CSS

Tags: css, vbulletin

I'm using the vBulletin forum software. I want to hide many elements using CSS where I will add my selectors in the additional.css file to override the main CSS.

If I made many elemnts hidden will this slow the download of pages?

Comment: Hiding the elements without removing them isn’t going to slow anything much, no, but it’s certainly not going to speed things up, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes but only by a trillionth of a second or so so you don't need to to worry